# AppleScript in Yosemite can't enter numbers in keystrokes

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite

On OS X Yosemite (Version 10.10.4)
the AppleScript

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    delay 1

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "ABC123def"
    end tell
end tell
```

Results in

```
ABCdef
```

without the numbers "123".
The same is true for entering other numbers.

Bug or feature? ;-)

Comment: Same system, no problem here...

Comment: no problem here either.

Comment: No problem here. What other apps see this problem? What happens if you change the keystroke command to "key code 18" for the number 1? What is your system language setting?

Comment: @jweaks: Thanks. (1) "key code 18" --> "1". (2) My system language is german. (3) The problem occurred in Yosemite with a script I used in Mavericks for a long time to fill cells of an OpenOffice-Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

"Mausebedienung" was activated in "Systemeinstellungen" - "Bedienungshilfen".
So every number was mapped to a mouse-movement.

I'm sorry but at I don't know the exactly english translations. I guess:
- System Preferences
- ...assistance
- Mouse ...

Comment: Belatedly, in English in Sierra, it is `System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Enable Mouse Keys` which must be unchecked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I had to use key codes for numbers.

Example: I needed to cd into a file containing the number 3.

I tried:

```
    keystroke "cd ~/Workspace/reminder3"
    keystroke return
```

This didn't work.

The key code for the # 3 key is 20. (https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes)

So I removed the 3 and added the key code {20} line like so:

```
    keystroke "cd ~/Workspace/reminder"
    key code {20}
    keystroke return
```

and it worked for me, I hope it works for you